# ExoPlayer auto show/hide custom player controls

Tags: exoplayer

Is there an option when using a custom `PlaybackControlView` to auto show the controls like it works when using the default ones?

On my `SimpleExoPlayerView` I am setting:

```
playerView.player = player
playerView.useController = false
```

On my `PlaybackControlView` I am setting:

```
playerControls.player = player
playerControls.showTimeoutMs = 5000
playerControls.show()
```

The behavior I am getting now is when playing the video i see the controls for 5 seconds and then they disappear. Touching the player view does nothing.

Do I need to implement the show/hide behavior? Or is there a way to set it to work like it is on the default implementation?

Note: using ExoPlayer `2.6.0`

Answer (score 5):

good question.

The reason your controls are disappearing is because you have set `playerControls.showTimeoutMs` to `5000`. 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds, after which they are disappearing.

Setting `playerControls.showTimeoutMs` to `0` will prevent the controls from disappearing automatically.

Hope this helps!